# Assign $m$ tasks to $n$ workers, with $m \geq n$

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming, assignment-problem

There are $n$ students that share the same apartment. At each evening, one of them must prepare dinner for everyone. There are $m$ evenings to schedule, with $m \geq n$, and you have to assign any singular evening to one student at a time.

In particular, student $i$ is disposed to accept cooking for $c_i$ evenings, with $1 \leq c_i \leq m$. Let $S$ be the global set of evenings (eg. $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$), for every student we define also $S_i \subseteq S$: you may assign evening $j$ to student $i$ only if $j \in S_i$.

So, given $m, n, c_i, S_i$, you have to define an algorithm that assigns each single evening to an available student.

I think a solution can be found using linear programming, although seems a little tricky. Let $x_{ij}$ be defined as follows:

$$
x_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & \hbox{if evening } j \hbox{ is assigned to student } i \\
0 & \hbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then you have such constraints. Student $i$ can accept a max. of $c_i$ evenings, so:
$$
\begin{array}{cr}
\sum_j x_{ij} \leq c_i & \hbox{ for every student } i \cr
\end{array}
$$
You have to ensure that every evening is assigned to a student only, then:
$$
\begin{array}{cr}
\sum_i x_{ij} = 1 & \hbox{ for every evening } j \cr
\end{array}
$$
Now a way to include $S_i$ in the constraints is required. Before doing it we define:
$$
 p_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & \hbox{if evening } j \notin S_i \\
0 & \hbox{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$
So last constraints are:
$$
\begin{array}{cr}
\sum_j x_{ij} \cdot p_{ij} = 0 & \hbox{ for every student } i \cr
\end{array}
$$
Suppose you have $5$ evenings, with $S_i=\{2,4,5\}$. You'll have the constraint $x_{11} + x_{13} = 0$. Since it's a linear program, we have $x_{ij} \geq 0$ so the equivalence is satisfied only if terms are all zeros, i.e. those evenings ($1$ and $3$) are not assignable to that student.

I have some doubt with the objective function, that it should be the sum of every $x_{ij}$. Should we maximize or minimize, or are they the same for this model? We could also put a constraint to say that such sum must be equal to $m$ (the total amount of evenings to assign), but i think it's not mandatory since it's guaranteed by previous constraints. What do you think about?

Is there a better way to solve such problems?

Comment: I think a max-flow algorithm should work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem, [tag:assignment-problem], http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42652/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30600/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10591/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43266/755.

Comment: @AndyG That's like saying "I think an LP should work".

Comment: @D.W. Any duplicate among those?

Comment: @Raphael: Yes, solving max-flow can be accomplished with an LP, but OP did not formulate is as such. Approach from a simplex algorithm perspective may make less sense than Hungarian, for example.

Comment: @AndyG Max-Flow is *exactly* as powerful as LPs, so *of course* it works (provided LPs work). Without giving an idea for the reduction (leading to a *small* network), your comment does not tell us much.

Comment: @Raphael, frankly, I would prefer to close this as a duplicate of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem, but of course that's not how duplicates work.  (I'm only half serious here.)  All of those other questions are about more sophisticated variants of the question, so I don't know whether they're good dup targets -- I'll let someone else decide that.